# Clustering a boolean matrix in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

Suppose we have a Boolean matrix such as the following:

```
0 0 1 0 0 1 0

1 1 0 0 1 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 1 1

0 0 0 0 0 1 0

0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

interpreted this way: each row is a fruit and each column is a person. A '1' in position (i, j) indicates that person j would like to eat fruit i.
I would like to 'cluster' this matrix, creating sub-matrices that indicate subsets of people competing for subsets of fruit. In the example above I would like to see in output:

```
0 0 1 0 0 1 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 1 1

0 0 0 0 0 1 0

0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

and

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0

1 1 0 0 1 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Is there a simple way to do this, for example, in Matlab?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The description is way too informal and engineering something based on a single example is probably not a good idea.

Howewer: if the example just shows a 2 partition (which is my interpretation), this can easily achieved by:

```
- Create undirected graph G with one vertex for each row
- Iterate over all "N over 2" row-pairs (= nested i,j loop skipping symmetries)
- If the pair (rowA, rowB) shares some 1 in a column -> add edge (rowA, rowB) to G
- Compute all "connected components" of G
```

Any sane graph-lib will provide the primitives needed.